# Nodejs Unhandled promise rejectionwarning typeerror cannot read property Error handling?

Tags: node.js

I am a beginner to the `nodejs`. I have a function that's using `async` method and this function reads the JSON values and update to Database. but the problem here is ,sometimes i'm getting `unhandledpromiserejectionwarning typeerror cannot read property`  when reading the JSON value in that function.

**below is the sample snippet :**

```
proto.onWspresenceEvent = function (json_obj , cb){

    try{

       (async () => {


            var self = this;

            let event_state = 0;

            let id    = json_obj["SCA"].id; //here getting the error


        })();
     }
    catch(e){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

unhandledpromiserejectionwarning is caused due to syntex error of your code. You can try this may solve your problem

```
 proto.onWspresenceEvent = async (json_obj , cb)=>{

    try{

       await () => {


            var self = this;

            let event_state = 0;

            let id    = json_obj["SCA"].id; //here getting the error


        })();
     }
    catch(e){
    }
    }
```

Comment: This is not syntax error code dear friend....only sometimes im getting that error which means code is proper but im unable to handle the json reading erros in async method

Comment: await function must return a promise in your case not json_obj["SCA"].id is undefined because you are accessing before this json_obj get loaded

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of node, you **have** to handle rejected promise, a.k.a use a `.catch` phrase.

Where is your promise you ask? async functions always return a promise. Even if you wrote the function and there is no way its gonna reject- you have to place a `.catch` phrase.

**note**: the `catch` block after they `try` **does not qualify as promise rejection handler**. you have to put the `.catch` after your promise, like so:

```
proto.onWspresenceEvent = function (json_obj , cb){
    try{
       (async () => {
            var self = this;
            let event_state = 0;
            let id    = json_obj["SCA"].id; //here getting the error
            cb("sucess")
        })()
        .catch(reason) { // your error handling
        }
     }
    catch(e){
           cb("failed")
    }
}
```

The error is probably caused when your json file does not contain the property you try to read, so it throws an error. since this error is inside an async function- it rejects the promise with that error, but than there is no error handling for that specific promise and so it fails with this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
function yourFunc(json_obj , cb){
    try {
       (() => {
            var self = this;
            let event_state = 0;
            let id  = json_obj["SCA"].id;
            cb("sucess")
        })();
    } catch(e){
        cb("failed")
    }
}

yourFunc({ SCA: { id: 123 } }, console.log) // success

yourFunc(null, console.log) // failed

// can be rewritten more clearly as follow

function yourFuncClear(json_obj , cb){
    try {
        let id  = json_obj["SCA"].id;
        cb("sucess")
    } catch (e){
        cb("failed")
    }
}

yourFuncClear({ SCA: { id: 123 } }, console.log) // success

yourFuncClear(null, console.log) // failed
```